# Apollo - How to pass a Union type to ApolloClient

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using the Shopify GraphQL to apply a mutation as shown at the bottom.

I want to declare a union type for `ShopifyReturnUrl` in that mutation for which I have declared this:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const shopifyReturnUrl = gql`
  union ShopifyReturnUrl = String | URL
`;
```

However how do I actually get this into my ApolloClient instance which is currently defined like so:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    fetchOptions: {
        credentials: 'include'
    },
});
```

And for context, I'm using this in my React app like so:

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</ApolloProvider>
```

Finally, the mutation where I actually want to use `ShopifyReturnUrl`

```
export const SUBSCRIPTION_MODIFY = gql`
  mutation($subName: String!, $subPrice: String!, $returnUrl: ShopifyReturnUrl) {
    appSubscriptionCreate(
        name: $subName
        returnUrl: $returnUrl
      ) 
  }
`
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here:

- Unions can only be created for object types, not scalars like `String`.
- Type definitions are written on the server, not on the client. As a client, you can't add additional types to the schema that's exposed by the server since the server wouldn't know how to handle those types.
- If `appSubscriptionCreate` takes a `returnUrl` argument, then the variable you pass to that argument (in this case named `$returnUrl`) should be of the same type as the argument. If you don't know the type of the argument, check your server's [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/billing/appsubscriptioncreate#arguments-2020-10) or its [GraphiQL interface](https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/login) (if it exposes one). In this specific case, the argument's type is `URL!`, so that's what your variable should be.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually figured out using String as one of the types wasn't required at all so no union needed from my side (as confirmed by your third point). Nevertheless the above is useful knowledge for future reference. Cheers!